# Elixir Phoenix - enforce uniqueness on null

Tags: sql, null, elixir, phoenix-framework, unique-constraint

I have a set of Events, that have a date. The dates are only given in full days (e.g. 2022-08-06). To keep track of the order of Events within one day, I keep a `previous_event_id` key for each event so that I can create a linked list. When I create a first Event on a particular day, it will have a `previous_event_id` of NULL.

So a set of events in my DB could look something like this:

| id | date | previous_event_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | NULL |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| 4 | 2022-01-02 | NULL |
| 5 | 2022-01-02 | 4 |
| 6 | 2022-01-02 | 5 |
| 7 | 2022-01-03 | NULL |

Now, I want to enforce that only one event per day can have a NULL value. Is this even possible, and if so, how do I do this? I have the following code in my model but the unique constraint allows multiple NULL values.

```
def changeset(event, attrs) do
    event
    |> cast(attrs, [
      :name,
      :date,
      :previous_event_id
    ])
    |> unique_constraint([:previous_event_id, :date])
    |> validate_required([
      :name,
      :date,
    ])
  end
```

I considered using -1 instead of NULL, but (when not NULL / -1) it is also a reference, so then I would have a validation error on -1 not being an existing event id.

So, how (if at all) do I enforce a table to have only one NULL row? (Or, in this case, only one NULL row per date).

Comment: Using a hierarchical structure here seems overcomplicated.  Have you considered including a *time* along with your date to ensure uniqueness and proper ordering?  Or simply using an integer column to indicate the sequence of rows?

Comment: Yes, I have :) I actually had a timestamp together with the date before trying this solution, and it worked. However, that would lead to many writes in the case that you want to insert an event earlier in the order. (every event that comes after the insert needs to bump 1 up). Reads are less efficient in this new way, but my use case favors that a lot.

Comment: How exactly would that lead to many writes?  E.g. if you use an integer field for sequential ordering, you can still add a single row with a lower or higher value.
Unrelated: are you sure you have properly specified a composite key in your migrations and/or database schema?  The changeset layer may not have any effect unless this is properly constrained in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from @benwilson512 on elixirforum, which satisfies my use case. Putting it here for future reference:

You can do this by making a “partial index” that has a where clause:

`create index(:events, [:date], where: "previous_event_id is null", unique: true)`